# NetShareEnum Timeout

Tags: c++, winapi, file-sharing

The process for `NetShareEnum` sometimes takes upwards of 30 seconds, successful connections generally take less than a second, is there any way to set a manual timeout time?

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525387(v=vs.85).aspx) is quite silent on the subject. The [protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240321.aspx) includes a timeout that seems to be the actual connection timeout instead of a failure timeout. I found [SMB timeouts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2013/03/19/cifs-and-smb-timeouts-in-windows.aspx), which seem to be configurable to a degree (via registry settings) but I'd rather not mess up the default timeouts for a user.

If we can't set a manual timeout- is it acceptable to spawn a worker thread to run the process and kill that thread after a custom timeout (using `WaitForSingleObject` and `TerminateThread`)? Is there any possibility of crashing due to killing a thread running only that process?

Comment: A thread cannot run a process. Killing a thread (by means of [TerminateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717.aspx)) potentially has far worse consequences than a crash. [Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it’s still garbage on the sidewalk](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811) explains some of the not so obvious effects.

Comment: Hmm, very well. I suppose an alternative would be to run the child thread, and allow it to continue past the timeout and exit gracefully, but allow the parent process to move on after sleeping for the desired time.

Comment: @wizebin: another other obvious possibility would be to use a separate process to execute `NetShareEnum`, and kill that process when/if necessary. The OS can clean up after killing a process much more effectively than after killing a thread.

Comment: Does also `net share` (executed from cmd) take so long? Remember that if you wait a timeout (less than what the operation needs to complete), you might not get all the results. Is the server local or remote? Have you tried some tuning (e.g. passing _0_ to the 2nd argument - `level`, to get fewer info, although I'm not sure this would increase speed). The example in the link you provided shows how to use the last argument (`resume_handle`), you can use it to read in a separate thread permanently (if the shares might change during your program run). Anyway no need to forcibly terminate it.

Comment: @CristiFati I think you may be referring to `net view` and unfortunately it uses `WNetEnumResource` and doesn't work on roughly half of our client machines. (neither the function nor the command line program) However it is *much* faster. I plan on using this method only when that method fails. What black magic lets  `resume_handle` run on a separate thread?!

@JerryCoffin That's a great idea that I hadn't thought of!

Comment: I was referring to [`net share`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx); in this form prints local shares, which yields  the same results as `NetShareEnum` (with _level_ set to _2_). There's no magic allowing it to run in a separate thread, you'll still have to do it, but instead having 1 `NetShareEnum` call taking 30 seconds (and if it doesn't complete, you won't have any result), you can have several calls (less or equal to the shares number) that take together 30 seconds, by specifying a buffer size that allows storing a single record (instead of `MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH`).

Comment: I apologize, let me explain a bit further. NetShareEnum also prints a list of shared files for remote computers. I'm getting a list of shared folders for all of the computers on the network so the local shared folders are not as significant. I'm going to run tests that simply don't close the running child threads now and see how it works out.